# What is the relationship between r/K strategy and filial infanticides?

Tags: evolution, ecology, natural-selection

In other words, is the frequency of killing one's own offspring among species dependent on their location on the r/K strategy spectrum?

Comment: infanticide does not mean killing your own offspring, but offspring of your own species, the vast majority of the time animals are killing someone elses offspring. often it is a way of freeing up a mate to have your offspring.

Comment: @John You're right. That's what filial infanticide means. Google before critique.

Comment: I'm not sure if the short form is doing any favours. From your question, it sounds like you are asking "are species that kill members of their own species more likely to have 'cheap' or 'expensive' offspring?" That's still not very clear. Are you asking if infanticides in populations have been modelled before? Are you asking how to model infanticides in a population? Are you asking if the r/K spectrum is a sensible way of thinking about infanticide?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell there isn’t any work done on this specific form of infanticide. Here is a review on the subject [Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0162309579900049)

My assessment would lead me to believe the more r selected a species is the more likely infanticide (if it happens at all) done by the individual would be toward kin. This would probably be due to a need for resources.

One thing to recall though is that this actually violates a basic inference from natural selection. Fitness is measured by how much of your alleles you contribute to the next generation. If you are eating your own offspring you are effectively reducing your fitness. The individual may however increase their long term fitness by doing this.

A possible way to locate a species that might do this would be one that sexually matures later in life but has a relatively long reproductive life with the higher number of offspring being produced in the later age groups. Finding some life history on some K selected species might help you find what you are looking for.

I’m sorry that I can’t better answer your question. and for the spelling and grammar.
cheers,

Answer (score -1):

I think there is.

We know that each and every organism has sufficient resources provided by Nature for its survival.

Lets do a case study.

Let us say a population of 10 foxes lives in a jungle (whose biodiversity is undisturbed by any Non-Natural factors ).So, this particular jungle is well equipped to ensure the survival of 10 foxes.

Now, if we by any means alter the r-value - what we are actually doing is disturbing the initially stable number of organisms present in the jungle at different tropic levels.
That can occur by altering any little characteristic because all are interdependent by food webs and chains.

For eg, if the number of plants drops due to say fertility problems of the soil, then the number of herbivores would also drop (As herbivores' only source of food are plants).
This would result in competition between the carnivores for food as carnivores feed upon herbivores, whose population are dropping due to lack of sufficient food.

> **Competition** is a type of relationship from which no one benefits.Its kinda like war- There shall be a winner but there shall be no side that doesn't suffer losses.

So, back to the situation, competition among carnivores here let's say the foxes would increase day by day as the number of plants drops. So, foxes would resort to killing their own species so as to decrease the number of organisms vying for the *same* food i.e here herbivores.

You know what prevails the most in nature is - The Survival of the fittest.

**So, who do you think would be killed first ?**

The one who has had **experiences** in fighting for food and such stuff or the one who is an ***infant*** i.e has not yet experienced the dynamics of the intraspecific competition

> Its also worth mentioning here that of all the types of competition, Intraspecific competition is the most brutal as here organism compete for the *same* resources.

So, I think lesser the r-value of a location, more shall be the *chances* of filial infanticide.

PS: Note that I used the word *chance* because we can't predict 90 % of the natural things with certainty.We can make our best guesses. Say here, we don't take into account the protective nature of animals towards their offsprings.So animals are fiercely protective towards their own offsprings that they shall sacrifice themselves first while some eat their own offsprings first.

> The cheetah mom is a hard-working single mother, who raises two and eight cubs at a time. In addition to feeding and teaching them, she protects them from lions, hyenas, and other predators. To keep her litter safe, the mother cheetah moves her cubs to a new location every few days.
>
> Insects, fish, amphibians, reptiles, and birds also have been implicated in killing, and sometimes devouring, the young of their own kind.
>
> The best example that I think I could give to you is Cannibalism. We say that Humans are the most self-conscious beings.So, if they can resort to killing their own species 
>   for a) food b) money (female infanticide) , then why can't animals who have supposedly lesser consciousness of their actions than humans

Comment: Thanks, I too, would incline towards K-strategists as more prone to filial infanticide but I'd say interspecific selection is stronger in r-strategists as with the greater number of individuals, there's a greater potential gain in winning this race over (as r-strategists have a greater chance of dying, fixation in the population is infinitely more valuable). My thinking is, K-strategists invest much more so it is better to end an unsuccessful trial than to continue it for the rest of your life. But I can't evaluate all the other effects.